# Handling flexible PCB coverlay openings in fine-pitch footprints

Tags: footprint, fpc, flexible

I'm trying to understand how to handle fine-pitch pads on flexible PCBs. For example, a LIS2DH12 accelerometer uses an LGA-12 (2mmx2mm) footprint with 0.25mm wide pads on a 0.5mm grid.
[image: lga-12 footprint]

I'm doing a FlexPCB at JLCPCB, which uses a coverlay, and the design rules (https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/flex-pcb-capabilities) state a coverlay expansion of 0.1mm and they have a minimum coverlay bridge width of 0.5mm (really down to 0.3mm if I understand their feedback correctly). I believe these constraints are fairly typical and not unique to JLCPCB.

Given a clearance of 0.25mm between the pads of the footprint it's impossible to separate the pads with coverlay and, as far as I understand, the area in the center of the footprint also can't have coverlay because it would peel off during manufacture. The result is a large coverlay opening that encompasses the entire footprint.

My question is how to best deal with this. Is this simply "OK" or are there tricks?
Also: should I redesign the footprint to use rounded pads and maybe even anchors on the inside?

Comment: I wouldn't trust a small LGA on a flexi PCB. Even with a stiffener, there's a high chance that flexing of the PCB will break the solder joints. If you really want to do this, I think just remove the coverlay from underneath the whole chip and add the hardest stiffener as you can underneath the chip.

Comment: Good point! This part of what I'm trying to find out. I will need protection from the elements and one option I'm considering is epoxy plus possibly a fiberglass veil, which would add stiffness. The alternative is 0.2 or 0.4mm PCB. The whole thing is for a sub-1g wildlife tracker.